# Validation of a TextFormField Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

When I fill both of the TextFormFields, and press ADD, the window doesn't close as it should. Also is it possible to make it so that red warnings telling to fill the forms only show up after the validation? Cause right now whenever the window pops up, the forms already have a warning on them.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'activity.dart';

final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

class activityForm extends StatelessWidget {

  final activity act1 = activity('', '');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Add Activity'),
      key: _formKey,
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            maxLength: 24,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.sports_baseball),
              labelText: 'What do you want to do?',
            ),
            cursorColor: Colors.green[300],
            onChanged: (String? value) {
              act1.act = value!;
            },
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
            validator: (String? value) => value!.isEmpty ? 'Fill this' : null,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.notes_outlined),
              labelText: 'Details',
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            minLines: 1,
            maxLines: 8,
            maxLength: 300,
            onChanged: (String? value){
              act1.detalis = value!;
            },
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
            validator: (String? value) => value!.isEmpty ? 'Fill this' : null,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      actions: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Cancel'),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: (){
            if(_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
              debugPrint(act1.act);
              debugPrint(act1.detalis);
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }
          },
          child: Text('ADD'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to provide a validation for the user to make sure that he will put something in te text forms

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can wrap the column to  Form widget and add **key:_formKey** inside the Form widget. try below code :

```
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Add Activity'),
          content: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  maxLength: 24,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.sports_baseball),
                    labelText: 'What do you want to do?',
                  ),
                  cursorColor: Colors.green[300],
                  onChanged: (String? value) {
                    act1.act = value!;
                  },
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                  validator: (String? value) => value!.isEmpty ? 'Fill this' : null,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.notes_outlined),
                    labelText: 'Details',
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  minLines: 1,
                  maxLines: 8,
                  maxLength: 300,
                  onChanged: (String? value) {
                    act1.detalis = value!;
                  },
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                  validator: (String? value) => value!.isEmpty ? 'Fill this' : null,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text('Cancel'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  debugPrint(act1.act);
                  debugPrint(act1.detalis);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }
              },
              child: Text('ADD'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```